# How to approach $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

My textbook provided solution:

$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(x+2\right)^2+9}}$

= $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(x+2\right)^2+9}}$

= $\int \frac{ d(x+2)}{\sqrt{\left(x+2\right)^2+9}} $

=$\:\ln \:\left|\left(x+2+\sqrt{\left(x+2\right)^2+9}\right)\right|+C$

Can someone please explain why is that? I don't get it, how can you somehow just get $d(x+2)$?

EDIT:
I looked again and it is based on this rule, but I still cannot see how it obtained the answer.

$\int \:\frac{f\:'\left(x\right)dx}{f\left(x\right)}=\int \:\frac{d\:f\:\left(x\right)}{f\left(x\right)}=\ln \left(f\left(x\right)\right)+c$

Comment: Apply the [change of variable formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) with $\varphi(x)=x+2$.

Comment: Note that for any suitable function $f$, you have $d(af+b)=ad(f)$ where $a,b$ are certain constants.

Comment: Perhaps your textbook has a "table of integrals" including the integral $\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+a^2}}$.

Comment: @GEdgar ohh yeah...... I realized I missed a page. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this: $$3\sinh(t)=x+2$$ provided you are familiar to hyperbolic function $\sinh(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 2):

No. It does not work.

Try the following substitution:
$$x+2=3\tan\theta,$$ where $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: I've got Corona but still alive. Just to say: Good points about the interval. The student are usually used to solve indefinite integrals without considering the required intervals.

Comment: @mrs Be strong and courageous!

Comment: It's very kind of you. I hope GOD bless all nations soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

If we put $$\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}=u=\sinh(t)$$
then

$$e^t-e^{-t}=2u$$
or

$$(e^t)^2-2ue^t-1=0$$
thus

$$e^t=\frac{2u+\sqrt{4u^2+4}}{2}=u+\sqrt{u^2+1}$$

which gives
$$t=\ln(u+\sqrt{u^2+1})$$

Now, as pointed by MRS, replace $ u $ by $\frac{x+2}{3}$.